# Disable access to a subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site in `/public_html` folder and I have another one in `/public_html/addondomain.com`.

I want to disable acesss to `www.domain.com/addondomain.com` but users should still be able to access `www.addondomain.com` (contained inside `public_html/addondomain.com/` folder). I have an `.htaccess` in `public_html` folder. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^addondomain.com /this.file.does.not.exist
```